# I don't understand what happened to my order

Tags: node.js, json

I don't understand where this problem came from.
Please give me some advice.
thank you

```
0|prettyba |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
0|prettyba |     at async saveToDB (/root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:42:18)
0|prettyba |     at async /root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:98:9
0|prettyba | SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
0|prettyba |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
0|prettyba |     at Response.json (file:///root/Downloads/bot09/bot/node_modules/node-fetch/src/body.js:149:15)
0|prettyba |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
0|prettyba |     at async saveToDB (/root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:42:18)
0|prettyba |     at async /root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:98:9
0|prettyba | SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
0|prettyba |     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
0|prettyba |     at Response.json (file:///root/Downloads/bot09/bot/node_modules/node-fetch/src/body.js:149:15)
0|prettyba |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
0|prettyba |     at async saveToDB (/root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:42:18)
0|prettyba |     at async /root/Downloads/bot09/bot/prettybaccarat88.com.js:98:9
```

Comment: you are trying to fetch external resource but you are getting 404 html page instead of expected JSON

Comment: How do you think I should fix this?

Comment: - Double check you fetch call and the url in it,

- test it with some tool like Postman,

- check the differences here https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-LIMITS.md

- provide the actual code that you are using to fetch this JSON